# `Fetch` API Overridden. How do I access the original function?

Tags: javascript, replace, fetch, overriding

the Fetch API is totally mutable and can be replaced or removed by doing

```js
window.fetch = null;
```

or,

```js
var fetch = null;
```

or, the fetch property can be removed as well.

```js
delete window.fetch;
```

This means, if a legacy code defines a global variable named `fetch`, the fetch API cannot be used.

Is there any way to access the original `fetch` function in JavaScript?

Comment: maybe by somehow assigning fetch to your own reference before the nasty lib messes up with window ?

Comment: const fetch = window.fetch // window.fetch = null // use your own fetch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I appreciate your answers but none of you answered the question properly. The `fetch` function is already erased and we have no way to access it. In this case we can use the following simple hack.

This will hand us the original fetch function.

```js
function restoreFetch() {
    if (!window._restoredFetch) {
        const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

        iframe.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(iframe); // add element

        window._restoredFetch = iframe.contentWindow.fetch;
    }

    return window._restoredFetch;
}
```

Then, we can use the fetch API:

```js
const f = restoreFetch();

const result = await f('https://stackoverflow.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you delete from window object it won't be available any more...
but
You can use pollyfill to import fetch https://github.com/github/fetch#importing

```
import {fetch as fetchPolyfill} from 'whatwg-fetch'

window.fetch(...)   // use native browser version
fetchPolyfill(...)  // use polyfill implementation
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're not using packages then I can only recommend one thing.
As a first script tag you can do something like:

```
<script>
window.MYFETCH = window.fetch;
</script>
```

I know it's not perfect but then you can just use MYFETCH wherever you need it.